# Telephone field not getting displayed on front end

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want to display the Telephone field as required on the customer registration form. When it is not getting displayed on the front end.
Here are the screenshots.
https://prnt.sc/oumqt0
https://prnt.sc/oumr8c

Comment: try to clear chache..

Comment: @RkRathod Did that. If i choose tax option it gets displayed but not telephone

Comment: i think this configration for address details

Comment: @RkRathod Then how come it shows tax/VAT number  on that form

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-customer/Setup/CustomerSetup.php check this file telephone attribute of customer_address

Comment: You will need to attach the field to form, please check tutorial last 3 lines in InstallData.php. There you will be able to see that field is attached to forms. https://www.truecodex.com/course/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-field-in-magento-2-registration-form